# Origen de expresiones hispanoamericanas para referirse a un hombre homosexual

Tags: hispanoamérica, eufemismos, sexualidad

De estas que estoy trasteando con el *Diccionario de americanismos* y me encuentro con que en la entrada del verbo *[gustar](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=gustar)* hay una serie de expresiones usadas en diversos países para referirse a un hombre homosexual:

- Gustarle el arroz con tunco (Honduras, El Salvador).
- Gustarle el consomé de garrobo (El Salvador).
- Gustarle el arroz con chancho (El Salvador).
- Gustarle el arroz con popote (México).
- Gustarle las patitas de chancho (Chile).

Hay en estas expresiones un montón de palabras que desconozco, las voy listando:

- [Tunco](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tunco): cerdo (aunque como adjetivo significa "mutilado de algún miembro", "prenda de vestir que queda corta" o "cosa a la que le falta algún trozo" en Honduras y El Salvador).
- [Garrobo](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=garrobo): tipo de reptil (y también "pan alargado" o "arruga" en El Salvador).
- [Chancho](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=chancho): embutido de carne de cerdo (y también "conjunto de ambas nalgas" en Chile).
- [Popote](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=popote): tubo estrecho para sorber líquidos (imagino que como la acepción 4 de *[paja](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RTGhL0f)*).

Me han resultado muy coloridas todas estas expresiones (y alguna otra que he visto similar), pero no soy capaz de dar en todas ellas con la conexión entre el significado literal y el figurado. Me imagino el caso de *chancho*, que es un juego de palabras entre el significado de *chancho* como embutido y como "culo". Pero ¿cuáles son las conexiones en los casos de *tunco*, *garrobo* y *popote*?

---

<sub>NOTA: Sí, esto deberían ser tres preguntas diferentes, pero por no ser demasiado repetitivo haciendo tres preguntas muy similares, prefiero hacer una única pregunta. Se aceptarán respuestas aunque hagan referencia a uno solo de los casos propuestos.</sub>

Comment: siempre me he preguntado de donde surje decirles 
"jotos"

Comment: No entiendo "las voy listado". // Esta pregunta me parece que muestra poco respeto.  ¿Qué quieres lograr exactamente aquí?  Sí, hay muchos términos denigrantes para los gay en América Latina.  ¿Qué se logra con resaltarlos así?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Respecto al uso de "chancho" y "tunco", en España tienes otras expresiones culinarias similares, como por ejemplo la manida *"gustar más la carne que el pescado"*, o una que sólo he oído por la zona de Murcia y sus pedanías: *"gustar el solomillo con vena"* ([no me la he inventado](http://crowrincon.blogspot.com.es/2006/02/alcantarilla-sabe-que-existimos.html?showComment=1142187300000#c114218730584564712)). Por no hablar de los numerosos eufemismos del estilo de *"morcilla"*, *"salchicha"*, *"solomillo"*... usados para referirse al pene.

En general todas estas expresiones juegan con la idea de comer carne, donde se usa "carne" para referirse al miembro viril (por razones espero que obvias).
No creo equivocarme si te digo que esas expresiones americanas que usan diferentes nombres regionales de la carne de cerdo, se basan en la misma metáfora, más que en la acepción de "culo" (que lo tenemos tanto hombres como mujeres como el resto de opciones).

Respecto a los otros usos, se ve también fácil el paralelismo entre gustar de llevarse a la boca determinados objetos de forma alargada o fálica (pan alargado, pajita para beber), y gustar de hacer lo mismo con un falo propiamente dicho.

Algunas de las expresiones juegan incluso con ambos conceptos, como es el caso de las "patitas de chancho" (alargadas y hechas de carne).

Comment: Visto así parecerá que he pecado de inocente al plantear la pregunta. :-D Tal vez he pensado que la conexión podía ser un poco más rebuscada cuando no lo era...